# How should the Pokemon generation 4 remakes be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, pokemon

This upcoming week, the long awaited Pokemon generation 4 remakes will be released. The standard for generating tags is to include the full extended name of each game, for example:

- [pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum)
- [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire)
- [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green)

I don't recall this being an issue in the past, however the generation 4 remake will have a lengthy tag if using the standard format:

- [pokemon-brilliant-diamond-shining-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-brilliant-diamond-shining-pearl)

This exceeds the 35 character limit by 4 characters, meaning it cannot be used as the tag. How might questions for these games be tagged?

Comment: I swear they do this just to mess with us sometimes...

Comment: @Robotnik I thought the exact same thing…

Comment: How about pokemon-diamond-pearl-2021?

Comment: @Riley That's a good question. Why not post that one as an answer, and we can see what the community thinks compared to Wrigglenite's answer :)

Comment: Why aren't we using the same shortenings that the pokemon community uses? pokemon-bdsp would be a nice concise tag. I honestly don't like the excessive length of the other proposed solutions, or the existing tags you use as examples.

Comment: @Hearth we used to, but that was changed after a) The max tag length was increased from [25 to 35 characters](/q/12497/28182), b) there was a wider push to use official game titles wherever possible ([this, for example](/q/12181/28182)) and c) after [this tag rename request](/q/12831/28182) got a lot of community support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest [pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes) with [pokemon-brilliant-diamond](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-brilliant-diamond) and [pokemon-shining-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-shining-pearl) as synonyms.

Comment: I like `pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes`

Comment: I like this answer best, and we could also make [Riley's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16145/163757) suggestion a synonym as well.

Comment: Based on votes, pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes looks to be the most favored, with your, Riley, and PTwr suggestions as synonyms. @TimmyJim Do your magic :)

Comment: @Wondercricket [Done](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16157/163757).

Comment: I really don't like this tag, but I can't figure out a better solution...

Comment: @pinckerman A wise man once said "I swear they do this just to mess with us sometimes"

Comment: @Wondercricket it's funny because it's true

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [pokemon-diamond-pearl-2021](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-2021)

Answer (score 4):

Created the following [synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes/synonyms) for the tag [pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes):

- [pokemon-brillant-diamond](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-brillant-diamond)
- [pokemon-shining-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-shining-pearl)
- [pokemon-diamond-pearl-2021](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-2021)
- [pokemon-bdsp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bdsp)

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is [pokemon-bdsp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bdsp), google already seem to known what bdsp stands for. But it sucks for readability.
For what appear to be first bdsp question I went with [pokemon-bdsp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bdsp) and [pokemon-shining-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-shining-pearl), but most question will be valid for both <strike>daggit</strike> Diamond and <strike>mechagodzilla</strike> Pearl versions.

[What's the meaning of four trees in "location info" map view in Pokemon BDSP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392296/whats-the-meaning-of-four-trees-in-location-info-map-view-in-pokemon-bdsp)

Of course having [pokemon-brilliant-diamond-shining-pearl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-brilliant-diamond-shining-pearl) would be best.

In few years people will forgot what year it came out on, and many might not know those are remakes, so I'd suggest against such annotations in favor of just using game name.

Comment: [pokémon-bdsp] would be a good synonym. I personally am not a fan of the shorten tag using acronyms, which was the standard prior to the tag character increase