# Petition to slightly alter how we handle early Pokémon game tags (Gen 1 and Gen 2)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, pokemon

As established in [Pokemon tag problems (Gotta Tag 'Em All)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6957/28182), we handle Pokémon main series game tags in the following manner:

- **Generation Tag:** e.g. [pokemon-third-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-third-generation) - For questions about the 3th generation of games, that aren't specific about any individual game.
- **Game Tags**

  - [pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald) - for questions about Pokémon Ruby, Sapphire, or Emerald specifically
  - [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green) - for questions about Pokémon Fire Red or Pokémon Leaf Green specifically

This is generally great and works well for our format, we haven't had any major issues with this (barring one [tag length issue](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16143/28182)).

**However** something about this has irked me for years - the first two generations of Pokémon games do not have a secondary set of games, or a 'different story' split to necessitate a "generation vs game name" tag split. Thus, for these cases, the generation tag is the *only* tag for these games. i.e.

- [pokemon-first-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-first-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red), [pokemon-blue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-blue), [pokemon-yellow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-yellow), [pokemon-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-green), [pokemon-rby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rby) [pokemon-1st-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-1st-generation)</sup>
- [pokemon-second-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-second-generation)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold), [pokemon-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-silver), [pokemon-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-crystal), [pokemon-gsc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gsc) [pokemon-2nd-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-2nd-generation)</sup>

I personally think this makes these tags harder to use. For every other game on the site, including later Pokémon generation games, the game names still exist as a full tag, and thus I think it would be better we used [pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green) and [pokemon-gold-silver-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold-silver-crystal) as the main tags (leaving all the same synonyms in place). In other words:

- [pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-red), [pokemon-blue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-blue), [pokemon-yellow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-yellow), [pokemon-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-green), [pokemon-rby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rby) [pokemon-first-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-first-generation) [pokemon-1st-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-1st-generation)</sup>
- [pokemon-gold-silver-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold-silver-crystal)
  <sup>Synonyms: [pokemon-gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gold), [pokemon-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-silver), [pokemon-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-crystal), [pokemon-gsc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-gsc) [pokemon-second-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-second-generation) [pokemon-2nd-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-2nd-generation)</sup>

What do you think? Does this make sense?

Comment: Seems fine to me, although i wouldnt mind keeping the generation tag separate either, regardless of the lack of remakes. I would definitely add the [tag:pokemon-red-blue-green-yellow] and [tag:pokemon-gold-silver-crystal] tags either way though

Comment: This has always bothered me as well, so I'm all for it

Comment: That makes sense and is consistent with our usual tagging policy of having the game name as part of the tag whenever possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That makes sense and is consistent with our tagging policy of having the game name as part of the tag whenever possible. Another advantage is for searchability purposes: as per the Meta SE post, “[Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/162827)”, “the system automatically prepends the most commonly used tag to the question title when generating the page title (unless it's already in the question title somewhere) to help search engines find it more easily”.

So, using a tag that has all the game names in a generation would make the questions more visible to people who are looking for answers. Users are more likely to search for “How to do x in Pokemon Red” instead of “How to do x in Pokemon First Generation”. That tagging policy is especially useful when the question doesn’t specify which exact game the question is about.